# Microwave Sparking and several outlets not working

Tags: electrical

I live in a 1986 Mobile Home.  Gradually, over time, several outlets have quit working on me.  In the kitchen, when I went to use my old microwave, it sparked and made a loud crackle, but no breakers have popped.  I threw the old M/W away, as I thought that was the problem, but it wasn't.  Even the new one does the same so I know it's now an electrical problem.  Any suggestions, please?  Thank You

Comment: Did it spark *at the receptacle*, or *somewhere else*?

Comment: Both the receptacle and the microwave.  Sparked loudly !!

Comment: Where is the microwave sparking at? (I ask because trying to run a microwave with no or insufficient load is a sure-fire way to get a lightshow inside the microwave's cavity/cooking-chamber)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the receptacles are just wearing out, and the spring contacts have gone weak so that they don't grip the pin properly. If your microwave is sparking at the socket, this would tend to reinforce this idea.

If the receptacle contacts are not gripping the pin properly, there is a chance they will arc when current is drawn (as you have seen). Replacing the receptacles is the only way forward, I would think. All of them, even the ones which are still working.